# jQuery ScrollSpy Active Nav follows two divs

Tags: jquery, html, scrollspy

I'm having difficulties with the scrollspy plugin to track my active state while scrolling properly. I'm using the scrollspy.js library. I'm willing to optimize the plugin such as the change of states happen in certain offsets. I couldn't find any options in the plugin to perform the OffsetTop, since I believed that would solve the problem. Below is my HTML structure and the javascript to initialize the plugin.

```
    <div class="faq_tabs hidden_faq_tabs">
       <div id="my-nav">
          <ul class="stickyMenu">
             <li>
                <a href="#general" data-spyer="general">General</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#student" data-spyer="student">Student</a>
             </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#business" data-spyer="business">Business</a>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 id="general" class="spyon">GENERAL</h1>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h1 id="student" class="spyon">STUDENT</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 id="business" class="spyon">BUSINESS</h1>
    </div>
```

I've customized the script as shown below to get the data-attribute in order to add the active class.

```
    $('.spyon').scrollSpy();

    $('.spyon').on('scrollSpy:enter', function(){
        $('[data-spyer="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').addClass('spyedon');
    });

    $('.spyon').on('scrollSpy:exit', function(){
       $('[data-spyer="' + $(this).attr('id') +   '"]').removeClass('spyedon');
    });
```

This is the demo where I used the plugin:

http://frakton.com/scholarbiz-v1.2/?id=22

In the link provided you can see the erorr. I'm willing to avoid the active states for the both first items.

Answer (score 1):

Basically all I had to do was to optimize the script and avoid using the jquery scrollspy. Below is a javascript code which might help someone in the future.

```
   // Cache selectors
    var lastId,
        topMenu = $("#my-nav"),
        topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight(),
        // All list items
        menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
        // Anchors corresponding to menu items
        scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
            var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
            if (item.length) {
                return item;
            }
        });

    // Bind click handler to menu items
    // so we can get a fancy scroll animation
    menuItems.click(function(e) {
        var href = $(this).attr("href"),
            o = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top - topMenuHeight;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: o
        }, 300);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Bind to scroll
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        // Get container scroll position
        var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight;

        // Get id of current scroll item
        var cur = scrollItems.map(function() {
            if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
                return this;
        });
        // Get the id of the current element
        cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
        var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

        if (lastId !== id) {
            lastId = id;
            // Set/remove active class
            menuItems
                .parent().removeClass("active")
                .end().filter("[href=#" + id + "]").parent().addClass("active");
        }
    });
```

All you need to do is change the value of the class which corresponds to the menu or sticky nav one might have in the topMenu variable, and style the css for the active class.